# Error With move function Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using python 3.4.1 with windows and when I close my Tkinter I obtain an error message about move tkinter function. The app works fine, but when I close my app the shell reports me this bug message:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "E:/ProgramasPython3/Programas TKinter/JuegoPong/Pong.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ProgramasPython3/Programas TKinter/JuegoPong/Pong.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/ProgramasPython3/Programas TKinter/JuegoPong/Pong.py", line 89, in main
    pelota.dibujar()
  File "E:/ProgramasPython3/Programas TKinter/JuegoPong/Pong.py", line 35, in dibujar
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2398, in move
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".42952128"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python34

from tkinter import (Tk, Frame, Canvas)
import random
import time as time


class Pelota(Frame):
    def __init__(self, canvas, raqueta,  color):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.raqueta = raqueta
        self.color = color
        self.id = self.canvas.create_oval(10.0, 10.0, 25.0, 25.0, fill=self.color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245.0, 100.0)
        empezar = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(empezar)
        self.x = empezar[0]
        self.y = -3.0
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_reqheight()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth()

    def golpea_raqueta(self, pos):
        raqueta_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.raqueta.id)
        if pos[2] >= raqueta_pos[0] and pos[0] <= raqueta_pos[2]:
            if raqueta_pos[1] <= pos[3] <= raqueta_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def dibujar(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0.0:
            self.y = 3.0
        elif pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.y = -3.0
        elif self.golpea_raqueta(pos):
            self.y = -3.0
        elif pos[0] <= 0.0:
            self.x = 3.0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3.0


class Raqueta(Frame):
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=None)
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.color = color
        self.x = 0.0
        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 10.0, fill=self.color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200.0, 300.0)
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_reqwidth()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.to_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.to_right)

    def dibujar(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0.0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0.0:
            self.x = 0.0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0.0

    def to_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2.0

    def to_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2.0


def main():
    tk = Tk()

    tk.title('Mi Pong')

    canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    raqueta = Raqueta(canvas, 'blue')
    pelota = Pelota(canvas, raqueta, 'red')
    tk.resizable(0, 0)
    tk.wm_attributes('-topmost', 1)
    tk.update()
    canvas.pack()
    while 1:
        pelota.dibujar()
        raqueta.dibujar()
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)


main()
```

The App is an easy Pong game.

**Pelota is Ball
Raqueta is Tennis Racket
dibujar is plot
golpea raqueta is knock tennis racket**

Thanks

Comment: The `while` loop at the end tries to do another update after the GUI elements have been disposed.

Comment: @tobias_k If i comment the update the program not work and not solve the problem.

Comment: Don't comment the entire loop. A quick-and-dirty solution would be just to put that loop into a `try/except`, so the error is not shown. After all, as you said, it works nonetheless. A cleaner solution would be to do away with that loop and use the `after` method of tkinter widgets instead, to have them update themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you can find a nicer way but putting it in a try/except will end without any error.

```
     while 1:
        try:
            pelota.dibujar()
            raqueta.dibujar()
            tk.update_idletasks()
            tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)
        except Exception as e:
            break
```